# How to stay in same activity after clicking button in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am trying to develop simple feedback application. When user enters invalid data it should show error. After error is detected all fields should be clear and I should stay on same activity What should I do?Here's my code:

```
      package com.example.feedback;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Feedback extends Activity {
    String s;
    boolean fill=true;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_feedback);
        final Button bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt1);
        final EditText tv2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv2);
        final EditText tv1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        final EditText tv3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv3);
        final EditText tv4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tv4);
        final RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rg1);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                s = tv1.getText().toString();
                check();
                s = tv2.getText().toString();
                check();
                s = tv3.getText().toString();
                check();
                s = tv4.getText().toString();
                check();
                if (rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId() == -1){
                    Toast.makeText(Feedback.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                Toast.makeText(Feedback.this,"Press again to Submit",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(Feedback.this,Feedback2.class));
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    }
                });


                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            private void check() {
                if(s.matches("")){
                    Toast.makeText(Feedback.this,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                 }

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feedback, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

this is the line:

```
  startActivity(new Intent(Feedback.this,Feedback2.class));
```

after the click, change activity.
I suggest you to check login success in onActivityResult method and if it's true than start new activity